# full screen background with button

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I'm trying to create a full screen html template like this image(center of page):

[image]

in the pointing of man and some other points, i want create a click ables button, but because image full screen and fixed position, button in another screen size get other position.

my code for full screen image:

```
html, body ,form
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height:100%
}
.fullscreen
{
  z-index: -999;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed; 
  width:auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

  <img src="source/fullscreen.jpg" class="fullscreen" />
```

how to fix this problem for all screen size just with css? and center fullscreen image?

Answer (score 0):

You can set "margin" property - CSS, of all those buttons with respect to their respective positions.

Comment: thanks, but fullscreen height set to '100%' and when screen height get lower, margin pixel or percent not change button position.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of centering an image **both horizontally and vertically** is well documented at CSS-Tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

One of the examples (which is close to what you want and doesn't have the drawback of having to know the image dimensions in trying to use the method):

```
html { 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%; 
   background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qSmX.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Which looks like this in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/ukVNS/

Consult the link cited for the other methods.